# Service with bindService not is visible on task manager

Tags: android, service

My app has two components the main activity and a service in a first instance a build a service and call with `startService(Intent)` if i see in the task manager of my device i can see (1 process 1 service) but i need two way communication between the service and my activity.

Now i have to use the `bindService(service, conn, flags)` and the communication works like it's expected but i can see the process in the task manager.

Comment: "but i need two way communication between the service and my activity" -- then use Otto, or `LocalBroadcastManager`, or a `Messenger`, or any number of other options for sending results from the service to the activity, and use `startService()` for sending commands from the activity to the service. Binding does not magically provide "two way communication between the service and the activity".

Comment: is posible use some like ServiceConnection with `startService`

Comment: Yes, you can call startService and then bindService.